# how to retrieve a firebase/firestore document field as a typescript object

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know if want to get a field from a single firebase document, it's possible to write something like:

```
const users = this.dataService.get().subscribe( dataRes => {
  const userData = dataRes[0].id;
});
```

But, how do you I get the `.id` from several documents in a collection as a typescript object? `dataRes.id` returns as `undefined`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  Please edit the question to show in more detail the specific documents and data you're trying to query, in addition to the full code of the queries that you've already tried that aren't working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Edited - hopefully, this makes more sense?

Comment: So, you're saying you have a list of document IDs in a single collection, and you want to listen to all of them at the same time?  How do you define what "several documents" are exactly?